# C++: std::map and std::set aren't ordered if using custom class (not pointers)

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, stdmap, stdset

This must be something incredibly stupid, yet I can't manage to make head or tail from it.
This is the testing code.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <limits>
#include <random>
#include <map>
#include <set>
#include <stdlib.h>
class value_randomized
{
public:
    double value;
    long random;
    value_randomized()
    {
        value=0;
        random=0;
    }
    /*
    bool operator<(const value_randomized& b) const
    {
        if (value<b.value) return true;
        return (random<b.random);
    }
    */
    friend bool operator<(const value_randomized& a, const value_randomized& b);
};
inline bool operator<(const value_randomized& a, const value_randomized& b)
{
    return (a.value<b.value)?true:(a.random<b.random);
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    std::map<value_randomized,size_t> results;
    for (size_t i=0; i<1000; ++i)
    {
        value_randomized r;
        r.value=rand();
        r.value/=RAND_MAX;
        r.random=rand();
        results.insert(std::make_pair(r, i));
    }
    std::multiset<value_randomized> s;
    for (size_t i=0; i<1000; ++i)
    {
        value_randomized r;
        r.value=rand();
        r.value/=RAND_MAX;
        r.random=rand();
        s.insert(r);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I've tried overloading the operator< both within the class and outside the class.
I've tried both maps and (multi)set.
Yet I can't understand how the results are ordered.
I'll show the screens of the debug window

Debug screen1
[image: Screen1]

Debug screen2
[image: Screen2]

Even printing directly the value of the multiset gives as result something apparently unordered. These are the first results

```
(0.0515083,114723506)
(0.0995593,822262754)
(0.0491625,964445884)
(0.410788,11614769)
(0.107848,1389867269)
(0.15123,155789224)
(0.293678,246247255)
(0.331386,195740084)
(0.138238,774044599)
(0.178208,476667372)
(0.162757,588219756)
(0.244327,700108581)
(0.329642,407487131)
(0.363598,619054081)
(0.111276,776532036)
(0.180421,1469262009)
(0.121143,1472713773)
(0.188201,937370163)
(0.210883,1017679567)
(0.301763,1411154259)
(0.394327,1414829150)
(0.383832,1662739668)
(0.260497,1884167637)
```

Clearly I'm missing something, but what?

Comment: Your comparer is wrong (Broken [weak ordering](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weak_ordering)). Use `return std::tie(a.value, a.random) < std::tie(b.value, b.random);` instead.

Comment: @Jarod42 It works.Thanks. But why comparing it field by field didn't work? Edit: Oh, I see the link. I'm going to read it. Thanks again.

Comment: ... it's wrong because it would treat something like `(0.6, 1)` as less than `(0.5, 2)`. That's not how lexicographic ordering should be implemented.

Comment: `(a.value<b.value)?true:(a.random<b.random);` is equivalent to `a.value < b.value || a.random < b.random`. This means that `{0,1}` and `{1,0}` are both ordered before the other, which is impossible.

Comment: Now I see the problem. Thanks again, guys!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your comparison function does not do [*strict weak ordering*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weak_ordering) in accordance with the [*Compare*](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/Compare) requirement.

Fixing the existing code could be done like this:

```
inline bool operator<(const value_randomized& a, const value_randomized& b) {
    if(a.value < b.value) return true;
    if(b.value < a.value) return false;
    return a.random < b.random;
}
```

or simpler, use [`std::tie`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/tuple/tie):

```
inline bool operator<(const value_randomized& a, const value_randomized& b) {
    return std::tie(a.value, a.random) < std::tie(b.value, b.random);
}
```